# Append a column from a previous match in CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I've a CSV file with the following format (`;` is the delimiter):

```
KEY;..;..;..;..;id1;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..

KEY;..;..;..;..;id2;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..
SUBKEY;..;..
```

I need to take the `id` (6th column) from each line starting with `KEY` then append it to the following rows starting with `SUBKEY`. So the result should be something like this:

```
SUBKEY;..;..;id1
SUBKEY;..;..;id1
SUBKEY;..;..;id1

SUBKEY;..;..;id2
SUBKEY;..;..;id2
SUBKEY;..;..;id2
```

Any idea how this can be done in bash script?

Comment: (bash isn't a text editor)

Comment: I meant a bash script that could use awk or perl or whatever

Comment: indeed, any shell (csh, sh, bash, etc) can call awk or perl or whatever, so the question isn't specific to [tag:bash]

Comment: With CSV', you have to beware that fields can contain delimiters (semicolon here) if the field is quoted. Does your file have any such fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = ";" }
     $1 == "KEY"{ id = $6; next }
     { print $0 (NF? OFS id : "") }' file.csv
```

- `FS = OFS = ";"` - treat `;` as field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`)
- `$1 == "KEY"{ id = $6; next }` - if the 1st field `$1` is equal to `"KEY"` string - set `id` variable with the 6th field `$6`.

  `next` will force `awk` to jump to the next record (skipping the current one)
- `print $0 (NF? OFS id : "")` - print/output the whole record `$0` with condition:
  if there are any fields within a record (ensured by `NF` built-in variable) i.e. the record is not empty - append `;` (as `OFS`) and current `id` value to the end of the record

---

The output:

```
SUBKEY;..;..;id1
SUBKEY;..;..;id1
SUBKEY;..;..;id1

SUBKEY;..;..;id2
SUBKEY;..;..;id2
SUBKEY;..;..;id2
```

Comment: this is insanely beautiful! can you add some explanations?

Comment: @bachr, welcome. You have my explanation. Thanks for the question

Answer (score 3):

**Sed** solution:

```
sed -E '/^KEY/{s/([^;]*;){5}([^;]*).*/\2/;h;d};/;/{G;s/\n/;/}' file.csv
```

- /^KEY/{s/([^;]*;){5}([^;]*).*/\2/;h;d}

If the line start with KEY, keep 6th field in the hold space and delete the line

- /;/{G;s/\n/;/}

If the line contain field, get the hold space at the end and substitute \n by ;

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by doing this
sed -r 's|^(\S+)(\s+\S+)$|s/^\1.*/\&\2/p|' file2 | sed -nf - file1

Now I'm facing issue where I need to append on a CSV file a column with the name of the ESX where the server lies
[Append field to csv based on conditional search from another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487398/append-field-to-csv-based-on-conditional-search-from-another-file)